# form closing and remove items from form

Tags: c#, xml, winforms

The full code is down below to which there are two small issues to which I search and nothing.  The first issue is when I remove a selected item from the list it removes it but the list does not properly orders itself as it kinds of deletes it but the one before is the one that is there and not the one that I deleted.  Then this follows to my second issue to which when I close my form what ever I deleted from the list is not saved into my xml document.  So when I open the form nothing that I had remove was remove at all and everything is still there.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml;
using System.Resources;

namespace SaveOpenXmlTest1._2
{

public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    //ListViewItem employeer = new ListViewItem();
    //List<Employer> employer = new List<Employer>();
    List<Employeer> employeer = new List<Employeer>();

    DialogResult result;
    string filename;
    string path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);
    //private StreamWriter filewriter;
    //private StreamReader fileReader;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    //List<Employ> employ = new List<Employ>();
    //List<Employ> employeer = new List<Employ>();

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void saveToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (SaveFileDialog filechooser = new SaveFileDialog())
        {
            filechooser.Filter = "Xml Files (*.xml)|*.xml";
            filechooser.CheckFileExists = false;
            result = filechooser.ShowDialog();
            filename = filechooser.FileName;
        }

        if (result == DialogResult.OK)
        {

            if (filename == string.Empty)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Invalid File Name", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
            else
            {
                try
                {
                    //FileStream output = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);

                    //filewriter = new StreamWriter(output);

                    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

                    //if (!Directory.Exists(filename + "Employment History"))
                    //    Directory.CreateDirectory(filename + "Empoyment History");

                    if (!File.Exists(filename))
                    {
                        XmlTextWriter xW = new XmlTextWriter(filename, Encoding.UTF8);

                        xW.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
                        xW.WriteStartDocument();
                        xW.WriteStartElement("Employeer");
                        xW.WriteEndElement();
                        xW.Close();

                        XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
                        xDoc.Load(filename);

                        foreach(XmlNode xNode in xDoc.SelectNodes("Employeer/Employeer"))
                        {
                            Employeer em = new Employeer();
                            em.Employeerc = xNode.SelectSingleNode("Name").InnerText;
                            em.StartDate = DateTime.FromFileTime(Convert.ToInt64(xNode.SelectSingleNode("StartDate").InnerText));
                            em.EndDate = DateTime.FromFileTime(Convert.ToInt64(xNode.SelectSingleNode("EndDate").InnerText));

                            employeer.Add(em);
                            listView1.Items.Add(em.Employeerc);

                        }

                        //xW = WriteStartElement("Emplyment"); 

                    }

                    saveToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = false;
                    saveAsToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = true;

                }
                catch (IOException)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Error Openning File", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                }
            }

        }

    }

    private void saveAsToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    class Employeer
    {
        public string Employeerc { get; set; }
        public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }            
    }


    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       Employeer em = new Employeer();
        em.Employeerc = textBox1.Text;
        em.StartDate = dateTimePicker1.Value;
        em.EndDate = dateTimePicker2.Value;

        employeer.Add(em);

        listView1.Items.Add(em.Employeerc);
        textBox1.Text = "";
        dateTimePicker1.Value = DateTime.Now;
        dateTimePicker2.Value = DateTime.Now;
    }


    private void listView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(listView1.SelectedItems.Count == 0 )
            return;

        textBox1.Text = employeer[listView1.SelectedItems[0].Index].Employeerc;
        dateTimePicker1.Value = employeer[listView1.SelectedItems[0].Index].StartDate;
        dateTimePicker2.Value = employeer[listView1.SelectedItems[0].Index].EndDate;

    }


    private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        //try
        //{
            XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
            xDoc.Load(filename);

            XmlNode xNode = xDoc.SelectSingleNode("Employeer");
            xNode.RemoveAll();

            foreach (Employeer em in employeer)
            {
                XmlNode xTop = xDoc.CreateElement("Employeer");
                XmlNode xName = xDoc.CreateElement("Name");
                XmlNode xStartDate = xDoc.CreateElement("StartDate");
                XmlNode xEndDate = xDoc.CreateElement("EndDate");

                xName.InnerText = em.Employeerc;
                xStartDate.InnerText = em.StartDate.ToFileTime().ToString();
                xEndDate.InnerText = em.EndDate.ToFileTime().ToString();

                xTop.AppendChild(xName);
                xTop.AppendChild(xStartDate);
                xTop.AppendChild(xEndDate);

                xDoc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(xTop);
            }
            xDoc.Save(filename);

        //}
        //catch
        //{

        //}
    }


    private void openToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (OpenFileDialog fileChooser = new OpenFileDialog())
        {
            fileChooser.Filter = "Xml Files (*.xml)|*.xml";
            fileChooser.CheckFileExists = false;
            result = fileChooser.ShowDialog();
            filename = fileChooser.FileName;
        }
        if (result == DialogResult.OK)
        {

            if (filename == string.Empty)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Invalid File Name", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
            else
            {
                try
                {
                    //FileStream output = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);

                    //filewriter = new StreamWriter(output);

                    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

                    //if (!Directory.Exists(filename + "Employment History"))
                    //    Directory.CreateDirectory(filename + "Empoyment History");

                    //if (!File.Exists(filename))
                    //{
                    //    XmlTextWriter xW = new XmlTextWriter(filename, Encoding.UTF8);

                    //    xW.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
                    //    xW.WriteStartDocument();
                    //    xW.WriteStartElement("Employeer");
                    //    xW.WriteEndElement();
                    //    xW.Close();

                        XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
                        xDoc.Load(filename);

                        foreach (XmlNode xNode in xDoc.SelectNodes("Employeer/Employeer"))
                        {
                            Employeer em = new Employeer();
                            em.Employeerc = xNode.SelectSingleNode("Name").InnerText;
                            em.StartDate = DateTime.FromFileTime(Convert.ToInt64(xNode.SelectSingleNode("StartDate").InnerText));
                            em.EndDate = DateTime.FromFileTime(Convert.ToInt64(xNode.SelectSingleNode("EndDate").InnerText));

                            employeer.Add(em);
                            listView1.Items.Add(em.Employeerc);

                        }

                        //xW = WriteStartElement("Emplyment"); 

                    //}

                    saveToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = false;
                    saveAsToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = true;

                }
                catch (IOException)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Error Openning File", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                }
            }

        }


    }


    private void exitToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Close();
        //MessageBox.Show("Save and Exit", "Cancel", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
    }


    private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


    }


    void Remove()
    {
        try
        {

            //listView1.Items.RemoveAt(listView1.SelectedItems[0].Index);
            //employeer.RemoveRange(listView1.SelectedItems[0].Index, 1);



            if (listView1.SelectedItems.Count >= 1)
            {
                //return;
                listView1.Items.Remove(listView1.SelectedItems[0]);
                employeer.RemoveAt((int)listView1.SelectedItems[0].Index);

                textBox1.Text = "";
                dateTimePicker1.Value = DateTime.Now;
                dateTimePicker2.Value = DateTime.Now;
            }
        }
        catch
        {

        }
    }


    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Remove();
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: [This](http://www.sscce.org/) always helps for faster and better answers.

Comment: Step through the `button3_Click` event and the `Remove()` function in the debugger. Look specifically at the length of the `employeers` list just before and after the `RemoveAt` call. Does it change?

Comment: I tried moving things around and replacing it with other operators but still no dice. I am able to add to the xml file but when I remove something and close it and then when I open it back up everything is still there.  Nothing got removed even though it got removed from the list.

Answer (score 1):

```
Employers em = new Employers();

employers.RemoveAt(listView1.SelectedItems[0].Index);

foreach (ListViewItem eachItem in listView1.SelectedItems)
{
    listView1.Items.Remove(eachItem);
}
```

After meddle-ling around and some help found the answer.